# ReSharper detects "Expression is always true" in a wrong way

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

ReSharper seems to resolve this kind of situations in a very simple (too simple) way:

```
public ActionResult Payment()
{
    IOrder order = PaymentBase.GetOrderFromRequest(this.Request.Params); //this method can return null sometimes

    int payForm = order.PayForm;
    if (order != null)
        PaymentService.Check(order, "push", payForm);
    else
        LogsService.SaveDataLog(WebShopLogType.PaymentInfo, "order missing on push", (object)this.Request.Params.ToString(), "p");

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

My null check `order != null` is marked with "Expression is always true" message and because of that my whole `else` statement is treated as not necessary.

What I found out is that this assumpion is made based on `order.PayForm`. ReSharper assumes that calling `PayForm` property of `order` object means that it is not null for sure. Removing this line eliminates *"Expression is always true"* message.

It clearly should mark `int payForm = order.PayForm;` line with *"Possible null"* message instead.

Is it a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: Your logic seems wrong to me.  You check if `order` is null _after_ you already attempt to access the `PayForm` property.  Shouldn't that line be _inside_ the `if` statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here, the expression is always true because if order == null, a NullReferenceException will be thrown a line before, at:

```cs
int payForm = order.PayForm;
```

so if no exception is thrown, the order object isn't null

Comment: True, then it should mark this exact line as "Possible null exception" in my opinion.